# A radioactive element that only emits beta rays

Tags: radioactivity

Are there any radioactive elements which only emit beta rays?

If not, are there any radioactive elements that only emit beta and gamma rays?

Comment: Why, many. $^{14}\rm C$ will do.

Comment: And how rapidly does it emit electrons? Also, it would be appreciated if you could give a comprehensive list of all such isotopes.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "list of pure beta emitters"?

Comment: @AbdulMoizQureshi "And how rapidly does it emit electrons?" – Do you know the concept of activity, decay constant, and half life?

Comment: Loong, no, only halflife. I also know that the more the halflife, the less tge radiation.

Comment: Ian Bush: Thanks! I tried a lot of other wordings that amounted to the same thing, but got no relevant results.

Answer (score 4):

In the long list of nuclides that are considered for radiation protection (taken from [ICRP, 2008. Nuclear Decay Data for Dosimetric Calculations. ICRP Publication 107. *Ann. ICRP* 38 (3)](http://www.icrp.org/publication.asp?id=ICRP%20Publication%20107)), we can find the following pure beta emitters and their half-lives:

H-3 (12.32 a)
Be-10 (1.51E+6 a)
C-14 (5.70E+3 a)
Si-32 (132 a)
P-32 (14.263 d)
P-33 (25.34 d)
S-35 (87.51 d)
Ar-39 (269 a)
Ar-42 (32.9 a)
Fe-60 (1.5E+6 a)
Ni-63 (100.1 a)
Ni-66 (54.6 h)
Se-79 (2.95E+5 a)
Rb-87 (4.923E+10 a)
Sr-90 (28.79 a)
Zr-93 (1.53E+6 a)
Ru-106 (373.59 d)
Pd-107 (6.5E+6 a)
Cd-113 (7.7E+15 a)
Cd-118 (50.3 min)
In-115 (4.41E+14 a)
Sn-121 (27.03 h)
Cs-135 (2.3E+6 a)
Re-187 (4.12E+10 a)
Pt-202 (44 h)
Pb-209 (3.253 h)
Bi-212n (7.0 min)
Cf-255 (85 min)

Comment: I'd upvote, but don't have enough reputation. Which one of those has a high rate of beta particle emission?

Comment: @AbdulMoizQureshi - you are given the link to the reference in the answer. Perhaps you should look through that to find the information you want.